# XML data Print with tag

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

Here is my XML. I need to print with tags.

```
 $XMLData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <GetItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>ABC</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
    <ItemID>123456</ItemID>
    <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>';

$XMLData .= '<IncludeItemSpecifics>True</IncludeItemSpecifics>
              </GetItemRequest>';

echo $XMLData;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for show without html tag :

```
$XMLData = 'Your Html Code';    
echo htmlentities($XMLData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
echo htmlentities($XMLData);
```

For line break Try:

```
echo nl2br(htmlentities($XMLData));
```

Php Documention: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: Know new things thanx #Delwar